# Android how to save realm results with onSaveInstanceState for screen rotation

Tags: android, realm, orientation, realm-mobile-platform, onsaveinstancestate

My problem is this:
When i open dialog fragment, i send realm and realm results from activity to dialog fragment. I always send different realm results to dialog fragment, depending what i click in activity. This is code in dialog fragment where i receive realm and realmResults from activity, when i click to open dialog fragment:

```
  public void setChangeNoteListener(ChangeNoteListener mChangeNoteListener, RealmResults<Drop> realmResults, Realm realm) {
        mNotelistener = mChangeNoteListener;
        mRealmResolts = realmResults;
        mRealm = realm;
    }
```

After i receive them, i use them for showing some data in dialog fragment.

Problem is when i change app orientation, app get crushed because i can not use realm results anymore.
My question is, how to save the whole realm results with onSaveInstanceStat and when app orientation change, to use that realm results again.

Note that in realm results is not only one item, there is more items.

EDIT:
I save date from realm with

```
 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Bundle argumetns = getArguments();
        int position = argumetns.getInt("POSITION");
        outState.putString("myTitle", String.valueOf(mRealmResolts.get(position).getWhat()));
        outState.putString("myNote", String.valueOf(mRealmResolts.get(position).getWhat_note()));
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

When i load app i load app like this:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mBtnClose = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_note);
        mBtnDelete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_delete_note);
        mEditTextTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text_naslov);
        mEditTextNote = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text_note);
        mBtnEdit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_edit);
        mBtnCompleted = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_completed);
        mBtnSave = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_save);
        mBtnForward = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_forward);
        mBucketNoteTime = (BucketPickerView) view.findViewById(R.id.bpv_date_in_note);
        mBucketNoteTimeNonSelected = (BucketPickerView_Unselected) view.findViewById(R.id.bpv_date_in_note_unselected);
        mSwitchButton = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switchButtonNote);
        mSwitchChangeDate = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switchChangeDate);
        mSwitchNoteText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.switchTextAbboveNote);
        dialogPickerButtonNote = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_picker_button_note);


        mBtnClose.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnCompleted.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnForward.setOnClickListener(this);
        dialogPickerButtonNote.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d("realmtest", "onViewCreated: prvi");
            String mojStringTitle = savedInstanceState.getString("myTitle");
            String mojStringNote = savedInstanceState.getString("myNote");
            mEditTextTitle.setText(mojStringTitle);
            mEditTextNote.setText(mojStringNote);
            buttonWhenSaveVisibility();
            setTitleNoteTextToDialogNote();
        }
        else {
            buttonWhenSaveVisibility();

            setTitleNoteTextToDialogNote();
        }
  }
```

App get crushed when i rotate screan and and call method setTitleNoteTextToDialogNote() on this line of code (when i try to get data from realm).

```
        mEditTextTitle.setText(mRealmResolts.get(position).getWhat());
```

Here is error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.realm.RealmModel io.realm.RealmResults.get(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.petar.android.simplenote.DialogNote.setTitleNoteTextToDialogNote(DialogNote.java:231)
                      at com.petar.android.simplenote.DialogNote.onViewCreated(DialogNote.java:134)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1127)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1272)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:600)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                      at com.petar.android.simplenote.ActivityMain.onStart(ActivityMain.java:296)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6696)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4519) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: First of all you will have to know which functions are called when orientation changes. These are the functions that are called : onPause| onSaveInstanceState|onStop|onCreate|onStart |onResume . Secondly, what is the error you get? I guess something is called on the functions i just mentioned which crushes your application - probably you are calling something that hasn't been initialised. A good idea would be to  create a class and extend Application - there you should initialize your realm database and everytime you need something you could call it through that class-which is always init.

Comment: App get crushed when i want to get data from realm database, because realmResults do not exist. Can i save reamResult in onsaveinstantstate like i would do with string and then pull back realm results when i change orientation.

Comment: Is that database initialized? A way to be sure that it's always going to be initialized it what i mentioned above - through the class which extends Application. Could you share the error log?

Comment: I add edit in the first post. Yes realm is not initialized after orientation change. Its give me null point exception when i try to get data from realm.

Comment: I want that in saveinstantstates() store realm resutls and when orientation change to use that stored realmResults again. Is taht possible?, just like i would save utState.putString("myTitle", String.valueOf(mRealmResolts.get(position).getWhat()));  Is there option to save the whole realmreuslts like that

Comment: The code that calls `setChangeNoteListener` isn't here even though that's the cause of the error. But I do wonder why you're trying to persist the data to a bundle when it's already persisted in the database....

Comment: @beginner Just a [reference](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#best-practices) to what i was saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RealmResults<T>` represents the query results you obtain from the Realm instance.

Realm is a database. It stores things. It's a persistence solution.

If there is something in the Realm, then that means you don't have to persist it in `onSaveInstanceState()`, because it's already in the Realm file.

You should just recreate the `RealmResults<T>` with the same `sort` parameter and you should be fine.

Also, seek your bug in whatever calls `setChangeNoteListener` and doesn't initialize the RealmResults.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but i have so many different variations of realm results. They all depend on what i click in activity, then i send that sorting option to dialog fragment. I will try this, however i will have lots of if conditions to recreate realmresulsts with correct sorting iptions

Comment: You should save your selected sorting condition then

Comment: I done like you said and its working. I saved sorting in shared preferance and then i just recreate realmResults.