# Android how to recreate realm results after dialog fragment rotation with the same sorting parameter before rotation

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

This is my problem, I will try to explain as best I can step by step.
Before i start i need to say that i use realm data base for the first time.

Now i go step by step and i will try to explain what im doing in my app:

In my Activity i have menu items in toolbar. Depending on what menu item i click, i load data in Realm Results and show items using RecycleView.

I load results using this code and in the end i add listener on database, so if something changes, listener will update everything:

```
private void loadResults(int filterOption) {
        provjeraHomeIliTrash = 1;
        switch (filterOption) {
            case Filter.CALENDAR_VISIBILITY: 
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllAsync(); 
                break;
            case Filter.NONE:
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllAsync(); 
                break;
            case Filter.SEVENDAYS: //logika.
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); 
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); 
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); 
                long start = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
                long end = start + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).greaterThan("when", start).lessThan("when", end).equalTo("deleted", false).equalTo("completed", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
                break;
            case Filter.LEAST_TIME_LEFT:
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
                break;
            case Filter.MOST_TIME_LEFT:
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when", Sort.DESCENDING);
                break;
            case Filter.COMPLETE:
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("completed", true).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllAsync();
                break;
            case Filter.INCOMPLETE:
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("completed", false).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllAsync();
                break;
            case Filter.BLACK:
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop_black).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
                break;
            case Filter.RED:
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop_red).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
                break;
            case Filter.BLUE:
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
                break;
            case Filter.YELLOW:
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop_yellow).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
                break;
            case Filter.GREEN:
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop_green).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
                break;
            case Filter.WHITE:
                mResults = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop_white).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
                break;
        }


        if (filterOption == Filter.CALENDAR_VISIBILITY) {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            mResults.addChangeListener(mChangeListener); //adding listener to database
        }
    }
```

After this, when i click RecycleView item i open dialog fragment with this code and i send realm and realm results to dialog fragment:

```
//Show dialog
    private void showDialogNote(int position) {
        DialogNote dialog = new DialogNote();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //saving position to 
        bundle.putInt("POSITION", position);
        dialog.setArguments(bundle); //saving position of clicked recycleview item.
        dialog.setChangeNoteListener(mChangeNoteListener, mResults, mRealm); //sending to dialog Change listener Realm and Realm Results  
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Mark");
```

}

Now, dialog fragment opens and receive realm results and realm instance with this code:

```
   public void setChangeNoteListener(ChangeNoteListener mChangeNoteListener, RealmResults<Drop> realmResults, Realm realm) {
        mNotelistener = mChangeNoteListener;
        mRealmResolts = realmResults; 
        mRealm = realm;
    }
```

**After this i populate dialog fragment with data from mRealmResults.
Everyting is fine till now.**

**Now problems starts:**

I try to rotate screen, before i rotate screen i call onSaveInstanceState() and save something so that saveinstantestate is not empty.

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        boolean screenRotation = true;
        outState.putBoolean("myRotation", screenRotation); //i just put something but do not use
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Now, screen rotate and i recreate mRealmResults with the same sorting parameters, but they are not in the same ordering as they ware before rotation. When i rotate screen, mRealmResults are not in the same ordering like they ware before.
After rotation, dialog framgent is populated with different data for some other position.
Here is code:

```
     if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

            Log.d("realmtest", "realmtest: prvi");
            int filterOption = AppBucketDrops.load(getActivity()); //loading from shared preference
            if (filterOption == Filter.NONE) {
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllAsync(); //Trazimo sve iteme normalno kako su dodavani
            } else if (filterOption == Filter.SEVENDAYS) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();// getInstance method returns a Calendar object whose calendar fields have been initialized with the current date and time. Imamo 2 vrste Calendar klase, ne funkcioniraju obe
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); //setiramo sate na 0 da se racuna od polnoci
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); //setiramo minute na 0 da se racuna od polnoci
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); //setiramo sekunde na 0 da se racuna od polnoci
                long start = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //sada dohvatimo svo to vrijeme u milisekunde iz calendara do polnoci
                long end = start + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //trenutno vrijeme + 7 dana
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).greaterThan("when", start).lessThan("when", end).equalTo("deleted", false).equalTo("completed", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
            } else if (filterOption == Filter.LEAST_TIME_LEFT) {
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
            } else if (filterOption == Filter.MOST_TIME_LEFT) {
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when", Sort.DESCENDING);
            } else if (filterOption == Filter.COMPLETE) {
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("completed", true).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllAsync();
            } else if (filterOption == Filter.INCOMPLETE) {
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("completed", false).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllAsync();
            } else if (filterOption == Filter.BLACK) {
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop_black).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
            } else if (filterOption == Filter.RED) {
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop_red).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
            } else if (filterOption == Filter.BLUE) {
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
            } else if (filterOption == Filter.YELLOW) {
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop_yellow).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
            } else if (filterOption == Filter.GREEN) {
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop_green).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");

            } else if (filterOption == Filter.WHITE) {
                mRealmResolts = mRealm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("colorPickerRoudIcon", R.drawable.ic_drop_white).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllSortedAsync("when");
            }
            buttonWhenSaveVisibility(); //changing button visibility
            setTitleNoteTextToDialogNote(); //populate views with data from mResults

        } else {
            buttonWhenSaveVisibility(); //changing button visibility
            setTitleNoteTextToDialogNote(); //populate views with data from mResults
        }
```

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/cmelchior/realmfieldnameshelper

Comment: you actually helped me with screen rotation 2 dayas ago, here is the link for that question i ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758625/android-how-to-save-realm-results-with-onsaveinstancestate-for-screen-rotation/41759710?noredirect=1#comment70711366_41759710.     Unfortunately i notice that when i recreate realm results, ordering is not the same as before. Is there any simple solution, everyting is working fine just ordering is not the same.

Comment: you should persist your `filterOption` parameter and restore

Comment: I do not understand what you want to say. I use filteroption to load what menu item i click in activity. In activity i click on menu item, then i save what i clicked in shared preferance. After that when i open dialog fragmen, i load in filteroption what i saved from shared preference and because of that i know what menu i click. So when i rotate screen, i load in filteroption what i clicked and because of that i know exactly how to recreate realm result. Its load the same results, the same realm size, just ordering is not the same.

Comment: Ah, make sure all of your queries are some form of `findAllSortedAsync` instead of just `findAllAsync`

Comment: I try and still dont show the same ordering. I also notice this: in my app i create realm results in activity, then i send that realm results from activity to dialog fragment and everything is fine. Now i change one diference, i try not to send realm results in dialog fragment, instead of that i recreate realm results wit the same sorting parameter and ordering is not the same. Could it be something wrong when i create new realm instance    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); but i do not close the one in activity.